# How to add ObjectId in array all elements in mongodb using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, lambda

I am using Mongodb and nodejs. I have stored array values in variable.below like this.

```
tag = ["58622e3bf39d570b21ece1b3", "58622e3bf39d570b21ece1a2", "58622e3bf39d570b21ece1r3"]
```

when i stored tag in mongodb database, I need to convert like this below.

```
tag = [ObjectId("58622e3bf39d570b21ece1b3"), ObjectId("58622e3bf39d570b21ece1a2"), ObjectId("58622e3bf39d570b21ece1r3")]
```

using nodejs, how to add objectId to array/list. without mongoose. is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your using the node js MongoDB driver, you can use the [`ObjectID`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html) method. This will return an object instance of ObjectID. Use map and pass the function in.

```
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

const objectIds = tag.map(ObjectID);
```

Comment: Hi DanStarns, If you don't mine, can you please give the solutions of the below query thanks in advance.         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58660375/how-to-find-strings-with-matched-letters-in-list-array-using-lambda-function

Comment: @RameshReddy sorry I don't speak python.

Comment: Hi DanStarns, If you don't mine, can you please give the solutions of the below query thanks in advance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59440712/multiple-images-upload-in-s3-bucket-using-nodejs-in-aws-lambda

Comment: Hi Dan, If don't mine, can you please help me the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60144231/while-increment-decrements-field-data-type-changed-from-int-to-double-in-mongodb?noredirect=1#comment106375983_60144231     thanks in advacne