# MongoDB Stitch - How to keep datatype to int (without changing to double) when incremented with update?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-stitch

I am using stitch in mongodb. In stitch, i write one nodejs function for increment and decrements purpose.

```
if(changeEvent.fullDocument.type == 'article' || changeEvent.fullDocument.type == 'poll' ) {
  context.functions.execute("notifyTopic", "article-created", changeEvent.fullDocument);
  var communities = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("utilo").collection("communities");
  communities.updateOne(
    {_id:changeEvent.fullDocument.community},
    {$inc: {"summary.postCount":NumberInt(1)}, $currentDate: {"summary.lastActivity":true} }
  )
} else if (changeEvent.fullDocument.type == 'comment') {
  context.functions.execute("notifyTopic", "comment-created", changeEvent.fullDocument);
  var posts = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("utilo").collection("posts");
  posts.updateOne(
    {_id:changeEvent.fullDocument.root},
    {$inc: {"summary.commentCount":1}, $currentDate: {"summary.lastActivity":true} }
  )
```

Now i have executed this function, the summary.postCount value converted from int to Double, I am usnig NumberInt also like this.

```
 posts.updateOne(
    {_id:changeEvent.fullDocument.root},
    {$inc: {"summary.commentCount":NumberInt(1)}, $currentDate: {"summary.lastActivity":true} }
  )

communities.updateOne(
    {_id:changeEvent.fullDocument.community},
    {$inc: {"summary.postCount":NumberInt(-1)}, $currentDate: {"summary.lastActivity":true} }
  )
```

this was not working event i have mentioned "summary.$.postCount" also, but there is no use.

I need the Increment/decrements values and datatype integer only. Please help me with the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider this document: `{ a: NumberInt(5), b: 50 }`. The field value of `b` if by default a `double`. If you do this operation from Mongo Shell: `db.collection.updateOne( { }, { $inc: { a: NumberInt(1), b: NumberInt(1) } } )`, both the values of `a` and `b` are incremented by 1. The datatypes of `a` (integer) and `b` (double) will remain same.

Comment: @prasad Document like this summary:{postCount:1, lastActivity: date} datatype is Int, but when i execute the above the code, datatype convereted from int to double

Comment: Can you check for a specific document and see before and after update? How did you check if the type is `int`?

Comment: @prasad I have checked in mongodb atlas. In stitch, i write the function

Comment: @prasad NumberInt not accepted in that function, when I put NumberInt, the increments/decrements not happens in that function

Comment: The syntax to specify an integer might be different. For example in Mongo Shell it is `NumberInt()` and with NodeJS driver it is `Int32()`. You have to refer the API docs for correct syntax.

Comment: See if this is what you are looking for: [stitch functions - creating explicit BSON types](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/functions/utilities/index.html#creating-explicit-bson-types)

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

1. You're right when you do this `{$inc: {"summary.commentCount":1}` it
   would convert any `Int32` field to `Double`.
2. So at first you should've tried
   `{$inc: {"summary.commentCount":NumberInt(1)}`.
3. Now it's
   already converted to double for further queries using step 2 is useless. You need to set your field back to original data type & then go ahead with your further operations.

On `MongoDB v > 4.2`, you can run an aggregation pipeline in `update()` to update all docs from double to int on field `postCount`.

```
db.collection.update(
    {},
    [
        { $set: { postCount: { $toInt: '$postCount' } } }
    ], false, true // 1) false is {upsert : false}, 2) is {multi : true}
)
```

If you're using `MongoDB v < 4.2` you might need to find a way to update all docs with their respective values, maybe read, manipulate data & update using [.bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/index.html) or [.updateMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html).

Comment: How to write the increment/decrements. In the above solutions just converted to interger right. but i need postCount in integer only, after increment/decrements

Comment: @RameshReddy : On an `Int32` field, if you use `NumberInt(1)` then it would always be `Int32`.. Since you've unknowingly used just `1` instead of above given it's converted to double, So you need to convert back to `Int32` & thereafter you can use `NumberInt(1)`.

Comment: I am using NumberInt(1) but the NumberInt not working event not increment the value also.

Comment: @RameshReddy : Can you test it on DB directly & let me know.

Comment: I am using Mongodb shell it's working fine. but I am using function to increment/decrements the count, NumberInt not wokring using nodejs

Comment: @RameshReddy : What is the issue, in general if you use node.js mongodb driver you don't need to use `NumberInt(1)` cause you wouldn't see this issue, but if you're using shell & get this issue then use `NumberInt(1)`, So stitch execute js code, Did you check if query is being executed ? Also when you're using `NumberInt` via a function what is the type of field you're seeing before running update ?

Comment: it's executed. same thing i told you right {$inc: {"summary.commentCount":1} using this code, the value increment but the value converted into double

Comment: @RameshReddy : So now do not use `NumberInt(1)` can you set the value back to `1` using `$set` operators & then use update with `{$inc: {"summary.commentCount":NumberInt(1)}`.

Comment: I am using NumberInt(1), the increment not happens.I have updated code in my query. can you see once

Comment: @RameshReddy : Do you mean to say update itself is not happening when using `NumberInt()` but happening when using `1` - Is that on both communities & posts ? then that's not related to this question, it's probably an issue with stitch config or function, as this question is more related to conversion of Int32 to double, you can close it & raise a new one with all stitch data to ask why update itself is failing..

Comment: Thanks bro, I will raise the new query.